# How do I enable multiple watch sources in sbt?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying to adapt [this react-play seed repo](https://github.com/yohangz/scala-play-react-seed). It contains the following code in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(
  watchSources ++= (baseDirectory.value / "public/ui" ** "*").get
)
```

I would like to add another directory to watch. How do I do this? I tried variations on:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).settings(
  watchSources ++= (baseDirectory.value / "public/ui" ** "*").get;
  watchSources ++= (baseDirectory.value / "public2/ui" ** "*").get
)
```

The `++=` leads me to think that the term on the right is a sequence of some sort, but I don't see how to add another directory to it. The above does not work - I get: `')' expected but ';' found.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a comma instead of a semicolon. `++=` produces a `Setting`; it doesn’t actually mutate anything. You can pass many of these to the method `settings` (via varargs), and like any other parameters you use commas.